# How to use bindings in angular 1.5 components

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, components

Trying to write a simple login page I've encounter some difficulty in understanding why the `.components` bindings doesn't work.

Example

template: `login.html`

```
    <form>
  <fieldset>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" ng-model="login.user.email">

        <label>Senha</label>
        <input type="password" ng-model="login.user.pass">

        <button ng-click="login.test({text: login.user})">
          Entrar
        </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

component: `login.js`

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('login', {
    bindings: {
      user: '<',
      test: '&'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
    controller: function ($log) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.user = {
        mail: 'email@provider.net',
        pass: ''
      };
      vm.test = consoleTest;

      function consoleTest(text) {
        $log.info('test! text:'+text);
      }
    }
  });
```

route: `router.js`

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(routesConfig);

/** @ngInject */
function routesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      component: 'login'
    });
}
```

The route does not load and shows up the errors:

```
stateService.ts:530 TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7096:54
    at Array.map (native)
    at scopeBindings (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7096:7)
    at getBindings (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7101:17)
    at Array.map (native)
    at getComponentInputs (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7109:21)
    at config.templateProvider (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7074:34)
    at invokeResolveFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2786:37)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16843:37)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16887:27
$defaultErrorHandler @ stateService.ts:530
(anonymous) @ stateService.ts:352
processQueue @ angular.js:16843
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16887
$digest @ angular.js:17982
$apply @ angular.js:18280
bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1912
invoke @ angular.js:5003
doBootstrap @ angular.js:1910
bootstrap @ angular.js:1930
angularInit @ angular.js:1815
(anonymous) @ angular.js:33340
trigger @ angular.js:3435
stateService.ts:531 TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7096:54
    at Array.map (native)
    at scopeBindings (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7096:7)
    at getBindings (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7101:17)
    at Array.map (native)
    at getComponentInputs (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7109:21)
    at config.templateProvider (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:7074:34)
    at invokeResolveFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2786:37)
    at processQueue (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16843:37)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16887:27
```

Just removing the `test: '&'` property in bindings and the route loads with no errors in console, but the ng-model does not link up to the controller so it doesn't update the input field with the hard-coded value.

How can I make those bindings work?

Comment: Why there is a "vm.test = consoleTest;" ? it is actually replacing the test function in bindings.

Comment: because I don't like the `vm.test = function () {...}` syntax inside the controller so I use `vm.test = functionName;` to be more organized and easily traceable if some error occurs because isn't another anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use angularjs [lifecycle hooks](https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks) to initialise the data you want:

```
vm.$onInit = function() {
  vm.user = {
    mail: 'email@provider.net',
    pass: ''
  };
}
```

You also won't need to bind test as you will have access to the controller in the component, as you are using a routed component not a stateless one.

If you were using a stateless component you would need to bind test and use it as a callback function to pass the data back after an event.

Comment: So you're saying the error there is exactly the function binding I defined?

Comment: I think that is what's causing the error because there is no need to bind test as it is defined in the controller. There is no need to bind user also unless you will be passing data from a resolve or something from the route.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, I removed the bindings and injected the variable initialization inside the `this.$onInit` hook function and it finally worked. So the bindings are for arguments in html tag properties of the component?

Comment: Yes the bindings are for passing data into the component. So this data can come from a resolve or if you are using the component in another `<login bind-data="$ctrl.foo"></login>`